# Configuring XCompose to Recognize Option Key on Arch Setup Running on MacBook

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm attempting to make Arch Linux recognize the left MacBook Pro <kbd>Option</kbd> key, so that I can, similar to macOS, use accent marks with certain keys. For instance, on macOS, I can press <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to generate an `e` with a grave accent: `é`.

- My `hid_apple.conf` looks like this:

  ```
  options hid_apple fnmode=2 swap_opt_cmd=1
  ```
- My `~/.XCompose` is set up like this:

  ```
  include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"

  <Super_L> <e> <e> : "é"
  ```
- The package `xev` indicates that my Option key is the `Super_L`:

  ```
  KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
      root 0x24c, subw 0x0, time 241407, (246,114), root:(1537,660),
      state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
      XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
      XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
      XFilterEvent returns: False
  ```